# Use of break statement in this solution, and time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, dynamic-programming

Note: I had [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73122384/use-of-break-statement-in-this-solution) this question on Stack Overflow, and got a suggestion to post it to CS Stack Exchange.

---

[The original question](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/bit-masking/practice-problems/algorithm/trophy-of-xorasia-0a2d466a/):

> You are given a list A of N integers. Here, N is an even number. These integers must be distributed into N/2 pairs and the power of each of the pairs is added.
> The power of a pair P(i,j) consisting of the i-th and j-th number is defined as the XOR of the two numbers A[i] and A[j].
> Write a program to determine the minimum and the maximum possible sum of the N/2 pairs.
>
>
> Constraints:
> N ≤ 20; N is even
> A[i] fits in a 32-bit integer, for all i

Since N is small, a brute-force solution (brute-forcing over all possible combinations of pairs) works.

---

[This solution](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/bit-masking/practice-problems/algorithm/trophy-of-xorasia-0a2d466a/editorial/) is based on DP with bitmasks.
It uses a `break` statement at the end of `for (int i=0; i<n; i++)` loop (just after `mask -= (1<<i)`).
**Question**: How to *prove* that this `break` still allows all cases to be tested?

---

What is the time complexity (closed form?)?
My take:
If T(k) is the time complexity when there are k zeroes in the `mask`, then

```
T(k) = (k-1)*T(k-2) + O(n)
```

(as there are (k-1) choices for `j`)

Required: `T(n)`:

```
T(n) = (n-1)(n-3)...(1) + O(n^2 * n)
```

If that `break` is removed, then

```
T(k) = (k choose 2)T(k-2) + O(n^2)
```

---

P.S.: I couldn't add `break` or `bitmasks` tags due to non-availability and low rep.

Comment: The link is not public, copy the solution to your post.

Comment: Brute forcing is boring. Let n be the highest bit set in any number. If it is set in all numbers then set it to 0 in all numbers, without changing the result. Otherwise, you can find an optimal solution starting by pairing numbers with bit n set, with numbers with bit n cleared, until all remaining numbers have bit n set or they all have bit n cleared. That should save a lot of work.

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  If you discover you posted on the wrong site, please delete the question before posting on the new site, and address all comments you've received.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  I see two questions here: how to prove something about the break statement, and what is the time complexity.  If you have two questions, please post them separately (providing full context for each).  Please try to ask questions that will be useful to others.  I don't know what "still allows all cases to be tested" means.  Please edit the question to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: I have pasted the solution [here](https://pastebin.com/R0m9R7iG). This solution is an [editorial](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/dynamic-programming/bit-masking/practice-problems/algorithm/trophy-of-xorasia-0a2d466a/editorial/) to the question.

Comment: By "still allows all cases to be tested", I mean that all possible combinations of the N/2 pairs are tested. This does not have anything to do with the specific "test-cases" that the problem has.